# React Hot Toast Stuck Behind <dialog> Element

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, dialog, react-hot-toast

## Toast notifications can't be seen with `<dialog>` element

**tl;dr**

Using the built-in `dialog.showModal()` causes the `<dialog>` element to always be on top, so toast notification are hidden behind the `::backdrop`.

### Intro

Not too long ago, the `<dialog>` element received some nice functionality for showing and closing it easily with JavaScript. It also came along with a new `::backdrop` pseudo-element for styling the backdrop overlay when the dialog is open.

Most of my projects use Next.js with Tailwind CSS. Because Next.js is built on React, I can take advantage of the [Headless UI](https://headlessui.com) package by Tailwind Labs, and I have previously used their `<Dialog>` component instead of the `<dialog>` element. In this project, however, I decided to try the built-in `<dialog>` element functionality, for it's accessibility features.

In this case, I am using the dialog to allow users to change their password. Naturally, it's important to display notification to the user, to let them know whether the password was changed successfully. I'm using [React Hot Toast](https://react-hot-toast.com) to handle these notifications, of course. In previous projects, when using Headless UI's `<Dialog>` component, I haven't had any issues displaying these notifications.

With the built-in `<dialog>` element the notifications are stuck behind it. This isn't a big issue if the `::backdrop` pseudo-element is transparent, but it always looks better if it is.

### Completed Tests

I've already tested changing the `z-index` on both the `<dialog>` element and the `<Toaster>` component, via Tailwind classes and the `style` attribute. Neither work, even with extreme values.

### Code

Keep in mind, I'm using the App Router.

#### In the `<RootLayout>`

```
<Toaster
  position='top-right'
  toastOptions={{
    duration: 3000
  }}
/>
```

#### `<ChangePassword>` Component

```
function ChangePassword({ username }: { username: string | undefined }) {

    const changePasswordDialogRef = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null),
          currentPasswordInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null),
          newPasswordInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null),
          formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)

    const currentPasswordValueRef = useRef(''),
          newPasswordValueRef = useRef('')

    const currentPasswordIsValidRef = useRef(false),
          newPasswordIsValidRef = useRef(false)

    const openPasswordChangeModal = () => changePasswordDialogRef.current?.showModal()

    const closePasswordChangeModal = () => {
      formRef.current?.reset()
      changePasswordDialogRef.current?.close()
    }

    const [formSubmissionState, setFormSubmissionState] = useState<
      'incomplete' | 'ready' | 'loading' | 'success' | 'error'
    >('incomplete')

    const validateInputs = useCallback(
        (inputId: string, newValue: string) => {
          if (
            (inputId === 'currentPassword' && newValue.length >= 8) ||
            (inputId !== 'currentPassword' &&
            currentPasswordValueRef.current.length >= 8) ||
            getComputedStyle(currentPasswordInputRef.current as Element).position === 'static'
          ) {
            currentPasswordIsValidRef.current = true
          } else {
            currentPasswordIsValidRef.current = false
          }

          if (
            (inputId === 'newPassword' && newValue.length >= 8) ||
            (inputId !== 'newPassword' &&
            newPasswordValueRef.current.length >= 8) ||
            getComputedStyle(newPasswordInputRef.current as Element).position === 'static'
          ) {
            newPasswordIsValidRef.current = true
          } else {
        newPasswordIsValidRef.current = false
      }

      const currentPasswordIsValid = currentPasswordIsValidRef.current,
            newPasswordIsValid = newPasswordIsValidRef.current

      const validInputs = [currentPasswordIsValid, newPasswordIsValid]

      const inputsAreValid = validInputs.includes(false) ? false : true

      if (inputsAreValid && formSubmissionState !== 'ready')
        setFormSubmissionState('ready')
      if (!inputsAreValid && formSubmissionState !== 'incomplete')
        setFormSubmissionState('incomplete')
      },
      [formSubmissionState]
    )

    let inputChangeTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout

    const handleInputChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = e => {
      clearTimeout(inputChangeTimeout)

      inputChangeTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
        const { id, value } = e.target

        switch (id) {
          case 'currentPassword':
            currentPasswordValueRef.current = value
            break
          case 'newPassword':
            newPasswordValueRef.current = value
            break
          default:
            null
        }

        validateInputs(id, value)
      }, 250)
    }

    const handleChangePassword = async () => {
      const currentPassword = currentPasswordValueRef.current,
            newPassword = newPasswordValueRef.current

      if (currentPassword === newPassword) {
        toast.error('You cannot set the new password to your old password.')
        throw new Error('You cannot set the new password to your old password.')
      }
      return true
    }

    const toastChangePassword: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()

      toast.promise(handleChangePassword(), {
        loading: 'Saving Password...',
        success: () => {
          closePasswordChangeModal()
          return 'Successfully changed password.'
        },
        error: 'Failed to change password. Please try again.'
      })
    }

    return (
        <>
          <div className='w-fit sm:ml-auto -mt-2'>
            <a
              href='#top'
              onClick={openPasswordChangeModal}
            >
              Change Password
            </a>
          </div>

          <dialog
            ref={changePasswordDialogRef}
            className='
              w-[calc(100%-2rem)] max-w-xs
              rounded-3xl
              shadow-xl dark:shadow-zinc-700

              backdrop:bg-zinc-100/60 dark:backdrop:bg-zinc-900/60
              backdrop:backdrop-blur-sm dark:backdrop:brightness-125
            '
          >

          <form
            ref={formRef}
            onSubmit={toastChangePassword}
          >

          <input
            ref={currentPasswordInputRef}
            name='Current Password'
            type='password'
            placeholder='••••••••'
            className='placeholder:font-black placeholder:tracking-widest autofill:static'
            minLength={8}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            autoComplete='old-password'
            required
          />

          <input
            ref={newPasswordInputRef}
            name='New Password'
            type='password'
            placeholder='••••••••'
            className='placeholder:font-black placeholder:tracking-widest autofill:static'
            minLength={8}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            autoComplete='new-password'
            required
          />

          <button type='submit'>Update Password</button>

        </form>
      </dialog>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: For now I'm choosing to just use the Headless UI component, as it does a great job with ARIA, but if anyone has a solution to this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using slightly different packages, but ran into the same issue with `react-hot-toast` that I solved.

I'm using material-tailwind [Dialog](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/dialog) with `react-hot-toast` in a Next.js app. I found that setting the `containerStyle` prop in the `Toaster` component  to `{{zIndex: 99999}}` moved the toast in front of the `Dialog` background blur so that the toast alert was in focus. I tried up to 9999 for the value of `zIndex` and it still didn't work there, but 99999 works for me.

`react-hot-toast` styling can be found here: https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/styling

The full `Toaster` component that worked for me is here which is placed in `RootLayout` in `layout.tsx`:

```js
<Toaster
  position="bottom-left"
  containerStyle={{zIndex: 99999}}
  toastOptions={{
    success: {
      style: {
        background: 'lightblue',
      },
      iconTheme: {
        primary: 'white',
        secondary: 'black',
      }
    },
    error: {
      style: {
        background: 'palevioletred',
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```